# Combine Composite foreign keys in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Consider *3 tables* in *MySQL* namely **T1**, **T2**, **A**

```
T1 -> t1_id as pk, a_id
T2 -> t2_id as pk, a_id
A -> a_id
```

Now, I need to create a mapping table for (**T1** to **T2**) such that

1. I can only map **t1_id** and **t2_id** with the same **a_id**
2. Mapping shall be *many to many*
3. Mapping of **t1_id** and **t2_id** shall remain *unique.*

Mapping table looks like.

```
M_T1_T2 -> map_id as pk, a_id, t1_id, t2_id
```

> **Question:** What foreign key constraints are supposed to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a unique constraint on `t1_id, a_id` in `t1` and on `t2_id, a_id` in `t2`. These pairs are unique anyway, because `t1_id` or `t2_id` are primary keys and therefore unique. But such a constraint is needed to allow a foreign key reference such a pair.

Then in your linking table, let's call it `t1_t2`, have `t1_id`, `t2_id` and `a_id` and two foreign keys `t1_id, a_id` referencing `t1_id, a_id` in `t1` and `t2_id, a_id` referencing `t2_id, a_id` in `t2`. That is the `a_id` has to be the same in both references records.

To force the triple `t1_id, t2_id, a_id` to be unique put a unique constraint on them or just declare them as primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE a
             (a_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (a_id));

CREATE TABLE t1
             (t1_id integer,
              a_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (t1_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
                          REFERENCES a
                                     (a_id),
              UNIQUE (t1_id,
                      a_id));

CREATE TABLE t2
             (t2_id integer,
              a_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (t2_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
                          REFERENCES a
                                     (a_id),
              UNIQUE (t2_id,
                      a_id));

CREATE TABLE t1_t2
             (t1_id integer,
              t2_id integer,
              a_id integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (t1_id,
                           t2_id,
                           a_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (t1_id,
                           a_id)
                          REFERENCES t1
                                     (t1_id,
                                      a_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (t2_id,
                           a_id)
                          REFERENCES t2
                                     (t2_id,
                                      a_id));
```

Comment: Yes, the concept is correct and does work perfectly in my applied use case. Thanks a lot.